# Does Apache Commons Net FTPClient use passive or active mode by default?

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

The app I'm working with uses `FTPClient` class from Apache Commons Net to connect and transfer files to a FTP server. I'm trying to establish if it's doing that in a passive or active mode by default and I can't see any references in the app's code or in the library itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **active** mode is the default.

Documentation for [`FTPClient` constructor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#%3Cinit%3E()) says:

> Default FTPClient constructor. Creates a new FTPClient instance with the **data connection mode set to `ACTIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE`** , the file type set to `FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE` , the file format set to FTP.NON_PRINT_TEXT_FORMAT , the file structure set to `FTP.FILE_STRUCTURE` , and the transfer mode set to `FTP.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE` .